# How to separate a variable into multiple variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
#! /bin/bash
readarray rows < Process.dat

for ((i=0, j=1; i< ${#rows[@]}; i++, j++)); do
   declare "row$j"="${rows[$i]}"

done

echo "$row1"
```

the output for this code is 10110 556 4433, I have tried using the same piece of code again changing the variables of "rows" and "row" however there is no ouput when i do this, How can i split up the variable "row1" into the 3 seperate numbers each assigned to a different variable, e.g row1_1 = 10110, row1_2 = 556, row1_3 = 4433

the input file consists of 5 rows and 3 columns of numbers:

```
10110 556 4433
10120 424 54
12452 123 534
22042 432 12
25321 423 73
```

The columns represent index time, burst time and id number respectively.

I need to work out:

- execution order,
- average wait time,
- average completion time

```
e.g execution order 4433>54>534>12>73. 
average completion time = 6132/5
(556+(556+424)+(556+434+123)+(556+424+123+432)+(556+424+123+432+423)) / 5

average wait time = 4174/5
(0+556+(556+424)+(556+424+123)+(556+424+123+432)) / 5
```

the endgame is to have each of these numbers assigned to a unique variable that I can later use to do math operations

output from od -c Process.dat

```
0000000   0   1   0   1   3   4       7   5   6       4   4   4   3  \r
0000020  \n   0   1   0   1   3   6       7       4   2  \r  \n   0   1
0000040   2   1   4   5       1   6       1  \r  \n   0   2   1   2   4
0000060   4       7   2       3  \r  \n   0   2   2   1   4   5       7
0000100   1       5   5
0000104
```

the values are different because i am using the example file to check outputs against the example outputs but should still act in the same way

example file and outputs

```
010134 756 443
010136 7 42
012145 16 1
021244 72 3
022145 71 55

outputs:
avg comp = 4141/5
avg wait = 3149/5
```

Comment: If you need arrays of arrays, move to a more advanced programming language. Perl, Python, Ruby...

Comment: sadly I have to use Bash for this specific bit of work

Comment: Hi, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: same response to your earlier question (since deleted) on this same topic ... review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update the question accordingly; in particular, provide sample input, the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) desired output; also, does the input file consist of just a single row or are there multiple rows in the input file ... and if the answer is 'multiple rows' then show the expected output for a file with multiple rows (eg, load all rows/columns into a single array?)

Comment: `specific bit of work ` Do you specifically _have to_ create different variables, or do you want to use them variables later? The variables just make no point.

Comment: I want multiple variables to use later as it makes the math needed later significantly easier

Comment: @markp-fuso I think I have now updated to provide all relevent info

Comment: "Makes the math needed later significantly easier" -- could you show the specific problem you run into trying to do the math _without_ this operation preceding?

Comment: still need to know what you expect the resultant variable(s) to look like; this is looking more like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in which case it may make more sense if you can provide some examples of how you plan on using these variables in 'the math needed later'; also, this 'math needed later' ... will this be done on a line-by-line basis within a `while` loop such that the 3x variables can be re-used for each line or do you need to explicitly save each line of values in a separate set of variables?

Comment: Why do you *need* to use `bash`?

Comment: (I echo what chepner says -- if what you really mean is "need to use out-of-the-box tools available on Linux", f/e, that means you have awk, and awk is _much_ better than bash for this class of problem; moreover, Python is just as out-of-the-box as bash is on modern distros).

Comment: `values=( $(<Process.dat) )` will load each value into a separate cell in the array(run `typeset -p values` to show entire array), from here `for ((i=0;i<=${#values[@]}";i=i+3)); do echo values[i],values[i+1],values[i+2]; done` will allow you to access each tuple separately; assuming this is not sufficient ... OP should provide an example on how the variables are to be used

Comment: @chepner I need to use Bash because i have been asked to, i agree that this would be mush easier with pretty much any language, because i am more familiar with other languages. But my tutor has insisted i use bash because i am pretty much new to bash and it's syntax

Comment: Your tutor is making you waste your time. There are plenty of `bash`-appropriate tasks they could assign to help you learn `bash`. This is not one of them.

Comment: update the question with a sample of the 'math'; need to know if the 'math' can be performed in the same `while` loop used to read the file (ie, variables can be re-used for each pass through the loop), or if the 'math' is done outside the loop thus requiring each row/column value is stored separately; also, do the results of the 'math' need to be stored in other variables or just dumped to stdout (eg, to console, to file)?

Comment: `I want multiple variables to use later ` Why not just use the actual data, instead of making the variables. It's just a means to an end, omit that part.

Comment: @KamilCuk it needs to work with other .dat files in the same format, this is just a sample file provided for the work

Comment: `need to work out: execution order, average wait time, average completion time` Use awk. Do not use bash at all. Solve one problem at a time, it will be easier. For execution order, seems like just `sort` will be enough. Or, Isee, use `cut` with  `paste -sd '>'` to join lines with `>`.  How do you calculate "completion time" and "wait time" from the input data?

Comment: @KamilCuk as stated in a previous comment I have to use Bash as this is work set by my tutor

Comment: Then start with https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 . Do not set variables to be used later. Read the file, and while reading it, parse it.

Comment: `bash` only does 'integer' math, eg, `echo $((5/2))` ==> `2`; to work with reals/floats you'll need to use some other command and/or language, eg, `bc`, `awk`, `perl`, etc, etc, etc; and while you can store the results (eg, `2.5`) in a `bash` variable, any follow-on 'math' will, again, need to use other commands/languages

Comment: @markp-fuso I don't need the float values I can keep in the form of a fraction

Comment: even for the 'simple' stuff you've asked for - `average completion time = 6132/5` / 
`average wait time = 4174/5` - you haven't told us how you came up with the values `6132` and `4174` (assuming these are somehow derived from the sample inputs); you've stated you don't know `bash` ... ok, fair enough ... everyone commenting in this thread knows `bash` but ... you have to give us the details we need to help you

Comment: @markp-fuso added now

Comment: saving `6132/5` as a 'fraction' means saving it as the string `6132/5`; you then mention you want to `later use to do math operations` ... are these 'math operations' also going to be done in `bash`, or some other language?  the reason I ask is that `6132/5` cannot be used by `bash` for 'math operations' so we're right back to the same, repeated question ... what is the actual 'math' you're talking about?  generating the string `6132/5` is (relatively) easy to do but a waste of time if you won't be able to use it later in your (`bash`) script

Comment: @markp-fuso I just need to generate the string as it won't be used in further calculations, the math operations later will only use the data in the file not the average times

Comment: what do you mean by `need to work out: execution order`? the comment reads: `execution order 4433>54>534>12>73` ... which appears to be the order in which the data current exists in `Process.dat`; are we supposed to pre-sort the file based on some (as yet) undefined order? are we supposed to save the sequence of `id` values and if so, in what form? a single variable? an array?

Comment: @markp-fuso as far as I am aware the execution order is just the order in which they appear in the file as the example i was given is as such, the output of the execution order would also just be a string of "4433>54>534>12>73"

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions/understandings (from OP's comments):

- input file has 3 columns: `index time`, `burst time` and `id number`
- each line of input contains details for one of the `N` sequentially run processes (where `N` is the number of lines in the input file)
- desired output are strings of the form `SUM/N` where `SUM` is the sum of execution/wait `burst times` for the `N` processes (aka number of lines in file)
- additional output is a string of the form `ID1>ID2>ID3>...>IDN` which is simply a concatenation of the values in the `id number` column
- OP has stated these outputs will not be used in follow-on 'math operations'
- it sounds (to me) like the whole purpose of this exercise is to generate some textual output representing aggregate metadata (of the inputs)

One `bash` idea:

```
sum=0
count=0

comp_total=0
wait_total=0

exec_order=
pfx=

while read -r index burst id
do
    exec_order+="${pfx}${id}"
    pfx='>'

    (( count++ ))

    wait_total=$((wait_total + sum))
    sum=$((sum + burst))
    comp_total=$((comp_total + sum))

done < Process.dat

#echo "comp_total : ${comp_total}"
#echo "wait_total : ${wait_total}"
    
comp_avg="${comp_total}/${count}"
wait_avg="${wait_total}/${count}"

echo "exec_order : ${exec_order}"
echo "comp_avg : ${comp_avg}"
echo "wait_avg : ${wait_avg}"
```

This outputs:

```
exec_order : 4433>54>534>12>73
comp_avg : 6132/5
wait_avg : 4174/5
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, however I can't seem to get the exec order to output the correct output instead outputting "32c_order : 4433"

Comment: I also get /4 instead of /5

Comment: Assuming you cut-n-pasted the code into your environment, I'm going to assume your input file came from a Windows environment and thus has Windows/DOS line endings (`\r\n`); if `od -c Process.dat` shows the character `\r` then you ***do*** have Windows/DOS lined endings in the file; one simple method to remove the line endings is to run `dos2unix Process.dat` prior to running your script (run `od -c Process.dat` again to verify the `\r` characters are gone); this (existence of `\r` characters) may also explain the miscount (`4` instead of `5`)

Comment: if still having problems, update the question with the complete output from `od -c Process.dat`

Comment: dos2unix fixed the exec order however the outputs are still 4 rather than /5

Comment: I'm guessing the input file is missing a line ending (`\n`) for the last line; again, update the question with the complete output from `od -c Process.dat` or edit the file and make sure there's a line ending on the last line

Comment: @Fravadona  there are a couple different ways to do the 'math'; I opted to mimic OP's summations (in the question); are you getting something other than `6132/5` and `4174/5`?

Comment: the actual values may be different as i did the math mentally however the calculations to get there should still be correct

Comment: My formula was wrong but I noticed that you can just set `wait_total` to the value of `comp_total` before updating `sum` and `comp_total`

Comment: @markp-fuso when using the example data i don't get the example outputs but I'm not sure why my com avg = 3149/5 and wait avg = 2298/5.  (the example data is given in the original question now). do you know why?

Comment: your `od-c` output shows file has Windows/DOS line endings (`\r\n`) and ***no*** line ending for the last line; `printf "\n" >> Process.dat` to add a `\n` on the end of the file; run `dos2unix Progress.dat` (should only need to run once) to remove the `\r` characters; make these changes to whatever is your actual input file and run again; if still having problems open a new question, provide sample input, code you've tried, wrong output generated by your code and expected code; this current Q&A is getting too drawn out and confusing by all the changes/additions to the original question